# WCF основные понятия

Tags: c#, wcf

Пытаюсь разобраться с WCF не могу понять некоторые базовые концепции.

1. Читаю, что это средство обмена данными между приложениями. Но при этом - это якобы некий отдельный сервис. Далее в гугле нахожу инфу, что сервис виндовс и WCF - не одно и тоже. Хотелось бы понимания в чем собственно разница между сервисом винды и WCF-сервисом ?
2. Совершенно не понятно, что такое ендпоинты и контракт. Здесь я вообще застопорился.

Помогите хотя-бы вкратце разобраться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если кратко: WCF-сервис можно рассматривать как API некоего приложения для клиентских приложений. При этом сам сервис не обязан являться частью приложения API к которому он предоставляет. Например WCF-сервис можно использовать для предоставления доступа к базе данных, которая, по ряду причин, может быть недоступна клиентам напрямую через ADO или другие адаптеры. `DAtaContract` объявляет поддерживаемые типы для обмена данными. `OperationContract` объявляет методы, доступные для вызова клиентами. `EndPoint` это фактически адрес, по которому доступен сервис для клиентов.

Служба windows - это программа работающая в фоне, как правило, без интерфейса. Предназначена для выполнения каких-либо действий без участия пользователя, например следить за обновлениями, вести логи и т.д.